# SQL for storing numbers from cold to hot for specific range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have a table that looks list this:  date, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5

for a given row, val1 -val5 are unique and between 1 and 37

Using T-SQL, How can I list numbers 1 -37 by cold to hot with their frequency for a given date range?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Sample Output (NOT ACTUAL):  Numbers by frequency descending:

36=0, 2=1, 5=1, 7=3, 34=5, 30=6, etc.

Comment: Kind of `[table of numbers 1-37] left join mytable ..`

Comment: sorry can you elaborate on this design?

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected results?

Comment: added something, but not sure how to generate inserts.

Comment: Do not share images for values that can be represented as text. Not all of us has access to imgur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a recursive CTE create the dataset 1-37 and then `UNION ALL` to create a dataset with all the numbers in the table.
Join the 2 datasets and `group by` the number and aggregate:

```
with cte(n) as (
  select 1 union all select (cte.n + 1) n from cte where cte.n < 37
) 

select 
  cte.n, count(t.number) counter
from cte left join (
  select date, val1 number from tablename union all
  select date, val2 from tablename union all
  select date, val3 from tablename union all
  select date, val4 from tablename union all
  select date, val5 from tablename
) t on t.number = cte.n and t.date between '2019-05-01' and '2019-05-31'
group by cte.n
order by counter, cte.n
```

Comment: worked great!!!! thank you. We are wondering about how smart a pbi NLP, AI report front end could be with this kind of data in another post.

Answer (score 0):

Generate table of 37 numbers and left join your data

```
   WITH E1(N) AS (
             SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
             SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
             SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
            ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
   E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
   E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
   numbers(N) AS (
             SELECT TOP (37) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
   )
   select n.N, count(t.val) 
   from numbers N
   left join (
        select dt, val
        from 
        -- your table here
        ( values 
          ('2017-01-01', 22, 23, 4, 22, 5)
        )  myTable (dt, val1, val2,val3,val4,val5)
        --  end of your table
        cross apply (
            values (val1),(val2),(val3),(val4),(val5) 
        ) t(val)
    ) t on t.val = n.N
    group by n.N
    order by n.N;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a list of 37 numbers (a recursive CTE is handy for this).

Then you can use a `join` if the values are unique in each row:

with n(n) as (
      select 1 as n union all
      select (cte.n + 1) as n
      from cte
      where cte.n < 37
     )

```
select n.n, count(t.id) counter
from n left join 
     t
     on n.n in (t.val1, t.val2, t.val3, t.val4, t.val5)
group by n.n;
```

If the numbers can be repeated within a row, then the above only counts the row once (it really counts matching rows rather than matching values).  If you want them counted separately, then unpivot.  For this, I recommend `apply`:

```
select n.n, count(v.val) counter
from n left join 
     (t cross apply
      (values (t.val1), (t.val2), (t.val3), (t.val4), (t.val5)
      ) v(val)
     )
     on n.n = v.val
group by n.n;
```